# Copy mongodb volume from one container to another container

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb configured as a docker container.

I have another mongodb which is configured as a 3 node replica set - which is actually 3 containers, each running on a different server and confiugred as a replica set.

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to clone the "data" directory between these 2 mongodb's.

The purpose of this method is to avoid mongodump and mongorstore which takes a long time for this large DB.

I made some attempts, when the continers were stopped on both sides of course, but seems like that after I copy the "data" directory to the replicaset, mongo starts in a state of "OTHER" instead of "SECONDARY" or "PRIMARY"

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

So finally, it is working:

Copy "data" directory from a SECONDARY repset container to a single mongodb container (old "data" directory removed from the single mongodb):

- Only one SECONDARY repset member is down (PRIMARY and other SECONDARY stayed up)
- single mongodb is down
  after the copy - single container startup OK

Copy  "data" directory from single mongodb container to ALL respset members (old "data" directories removed from all repset members):

- single mongodb is down
- all repset members are down :
- start ALL respset members containers
  after the copy - respset containers startup OK
  rs.status() - OK